# MediaWiki and page subscribing

Tags: mediawiki

Does MediaWiki offer a way to subscribe to pages and get noticed of changes? Does this require a plugin?

So far all I have found is this:
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Watchlist_subscriptions

Answer (score 1):

It's called watchlisting. You can then follow the feed on *Special:Watchlist*, or get email notifications, or read the watchlist via RSS/Atom feed.

Or, as mentioned above, you can subscribe to individual feeds for pages/categories.
https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Watching_pages

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension_Matrix/AllExtensions list most extensions: the extension [CategorySubscriptions](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aCategorySubscriptions) (beta) seems to be the closest one but only allows to watch at category-level, not page. It might contain some interesting code if you wish to develop your own extension.

Answer (score 0):

The best page describing all the feeds provided by MediaWiki I have found is [Wikipedia:Syndication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aSyndication).

Each page has a feed for its history. You can either access it from your browser from the history tab or you can build the URL yourself, it looks something like `index.php?title=SomePage&feed=atom&action=history`.